# How to add option box in "Edit Post" plugin API?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, posts

This might be kind of simple, but I couldn't find a way to do so in the WP docs. My plugin currently uses custom fields for things I could just have radio buttons/check boxes for each post. How do I add a little section where I can have such options rather than custom fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the example of a couple of checkboxes to set custom field values:

```
// register the meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_field_checkboxes' );
function my_custom_field_checkboxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'my_meta_box_id',          // this is HTML id of the box on edit screen
        'My Plugin Checkboxes',    // title of the box
        'my_customfield_box_content',   // function to be called to display the checkboxes, see the function below
        'post',        // on which edit screen the box should appear
        'normal',      // part of page where the box should appear
        'default'      // priority of the box
    );
}

// display the metabox
function my_customfield_box_content() {
    // nonce field for security check, you can have the same
    // nonce field for all your meta boxes of same plugin
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_nonce' );

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="my_plugin_paid_content" value="1" /> Paid Content <br />';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="my_plugin_network_wide" value="1" /> Network wide';
}

// save data from checkboxes
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_field_data' );
function my_custom_field_data($post_id) {

    // check if this isn't an auto save
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // security check
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) // spelling fix
        return;

    // further checks if you like, 
    // for example particular user, role or maybe post type in case of custom post types

    // now store data in custom fields based on checkboxes selected
    if ( isset( $_POST['my_plugin_paid_content'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_plugin_paid_content', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_plugin_paid_content', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['my_plugin_network_wide'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_plugin_network_wide', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_plugin_network_wide', 0 );
}
```

Following following hooks and functions are required for adding a meta box, see below references for more information about them:

### Hooks

1. [admin_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) (action)
2. [save_post](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/save_post)  (action)
3. [add_meta_boxes](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/add_meta_boxes)  (action) (you don't need admin_init in WordPress 3.0+)

### Functions

1. [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)
2. [wp_verify_nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce)

Comment: By the way - do you have a recommendation for API reference for WP? Their main docs I was looking at seem absurdly incomplete in the way of getting information about each action

Comment: Also having trouble getting the values to show their current value in the Edit Post page

Comment: Here's my current source. I apologize for it being bit clunky, I made a lot of changes at the coffee shop... and I'm new to WP plugin creation https://github.com/jphenow/WP-Difficulty-and-Platform/blob/experimental/difficulty.php

Comment: The code on github looks fine to me, can't test it right now. For the API docs, you can use: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks Or just put the action/filter name on google and you will find a pretty good tutorial about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is call in the WordPress world a MetaBox you need to use [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function to add your own.

there is a great tutorial and a PHP class you can use in your plugin at [deluxeblogtips.com](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html) I would suggest you use that for a starting point which will make your life easier.