# Problems with a custom meta_box

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, metabox, customization

I got some information on here which I am using for an Events site I am developing.

[How to add option box in "Edit Post" plugin API?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18290/how-to-add-option-box-in-edit-post-plugin-api)

However, I have changed the checkboxes for text inputs and when saving the post the values disappear.

Question 1: How can I get the values to save for each post?
Question 2: How do I pass this data to the post page?

Here is the function I am using, and here is an image of the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epg90.png

```
// POST PAGE EVENTS BOX

// register the meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'event_details' );
function event_details() {
    add_meta_box(
        'event_details',
        'Event Details',
        'event_details_content',
        'post',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

// display the metabox
function event_details_content( $post_id ) {
    // nonce field for security check, you can have the same
    // nonce field for all your meta boxes of same plugin
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_nonce' );

    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section">Fill in the following details for the event listings page.</p>';

    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-date" value="';
    echo date('d-m-y');
    echo '" /> <b>Date</b> - What date does the event start? <i>Please type in dd-mm-yy format with dashes included</i></p>';
    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-time" value="';
    echo date('H:i');
    echo '"/> <b>Time</b> - What time is the event starting? <i>Please type in 24 hour format with separator colon included</i></p>';
    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-subtitle"/> <b>Subtitle</b> - Is there an additional subtitle for the event?</p>' ;
    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-guests"/> <b>Special Guests</b> - Is there any additional guests at the event?</p>' ;
    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-venue"/> <b>Venue</b> - What venue is the event at?</p>';    
    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-city"/> <b>City</b> - What city or town is the event in?</p>';
    echo '<p class="misc-pub-section"><input type="text" style="padding:10px;" name="event-link"/> <b>Purchase Link</b> - Type the URL link for TicketABC</p>';
}

// save data from checkboxes
add_action( 'save_post', 'event_details_data' );
function event_details_data() {

    // check if this isn't an auto save
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // security check
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mypluing_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // further checks if you like, 
    // for example particular user, role or maybe post type in case of custom post types

    // now store data in custom fields based on checkboxes selected
    if ( isset( $_POST['event-date'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-date', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-date', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['event-time'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-time', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-time', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['event-subtitle'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-subtitle', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-subtitle', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['event-guests'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-guests', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-guests', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['event-venue'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-venue', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-venue', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['event-city'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-city', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-city', 0 );

    if ( isset( $_POST['event-link'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-link', 1 );
    else
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-link', 0 );
}


;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including any previously set values in the `input` field.

```
$value = get_post_meta($post_id->ID,'event-link',true);
<input type="text" style="padding:10px;" value="'.$value.'" name="event-link"/>
```

Note that the meta box callback get a post object not just an ID.

Additionally, you are not saving your fields at all. Instead you are saving either `1` or `0`. If you want to save your fields you can't just save a pseudo-boolean.

The third parameter of [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) is the value you want to save. You need:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['event-date'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-date', $_POST['event-date'] );
else
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'event-date', 0 );
```

[Please look into data sanitization though.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

Third, you are not getting past the nonce check.

[`wp_nonce_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) looks like this:

```
wp_nonce_field( $action, $name, $referer, $echo );
```

[`wp_verify_nonce`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce) looks like this:

```
wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $action );
```

What you need is :

```
wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_nonce_action', 'myplugin_nonce' );
```

And :

```
// security check
if ( !wp_verify_nonce(  $_POST['myplugin_nonce'], 'myplugin_nonce_action' ) )
    return;
```

Finally, you need to pass `$post_id` into your `save_post` callback.

```
function event_details_data($post_id) {
```

Now it works.

Comment: Actually, when updating a field it reverts back to the previous value? Any help with that?

Comment: I'll have to run the code. I can do that later today/tonight.

Comment: Hey @s_ha_dum any updates?

Comment: @LukeWolfenden : see the edit

Comment: EDIT: I posted a comment before but obviously didn't read your full reply.. Thank you it does work perfectly now & I will definitely read about Data Sanitization.